# How to switch Docker mode(Linux/Windows)? no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker

I am on Windows 10
Simple image building does not work

```
docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809' locally
1809: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
docker: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries.
```

Docker version shows

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.20
 Version:           20.10.10
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.9
 Git commit:        b485636
 Built:             Mon Oct 25 07:47:53 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.10
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.9
  Git commit:       e2f740d
  Built:            Mon Oct 25 07:41:30 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

My settings
[image]

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're in Windows Container, you need to switch to Linux Container.
Then, wait for docker restart and retry.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at my edit. It is the opposite case.

Comment: This is the 2nd case of this problem, you need to switch to Windows containers and try again.